# How to send SQL query result in CSV comma delimited format?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to send my SQL query result in CSV comma delimited format.
But it's coming as Tab delimited. How do I get CSV comma delimited?

I am using below parameters:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@recipients ='test@gmail.com'  
,@query= @Query  
,@subject= 'Test'  
,@attach_query_result_as_file=1    
,@query_attachment_filename='test.csv'    
,@query_result_separator=@tab
,@query_result_no_padding= 1 
,@query_result_width=32767 
,@append_query_error = 0
,@query_result_header =0
,@importance = High
,@sensitivity = Private
```

Comment: If you want an answer, you should add a tag that indicates which software you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the column separator in the line `@query_result_separator=@tab` but you haven't shown what @tab is set to. It looks, however, like a reasonable guess that it contains a tab character.

Setting it to ',' should work.

Check out [the docs on sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). They explain what each parameter does.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include @tab but your are right its tab character
but when I include ',' as separator it's not coming in csv comma delimited.
When I open that csv in notepad then Its not look like comma delimited.

Comment: And another issue i am facing is when I include headers i am getting dash(-----)
lines in CSV file